# Either hang or SQLITE_BUSY when trying to use Spring-Data-JPA with Sqlite

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am trapped between two opposite problems.

If I am using big `@Transactional`-s AND have NOT set `maxTotal`

```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      BasicDataSource ans = new BasicDataSource();
      ans.setDriverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      ans.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + sqliteDatabaseFile().getAbsolutePath());
      //ans.setMaxTotal(4);
      //ans.setMaxTotal(1);

      return ans;
   }
```

I am getting `error performing isolated work` -> `SQLITE_BUSY` exception.

And if I set `maxTotal` to `1` I am getting hang on

```
 Participating in existing transaction
```

log message.

My current solution is to try to apply `@Transactional` to smaller methods, but this is not easy because I am to distribute them between beans to activate between-class barrier.

Is there more logical solution?